# About the method of confirming the total value of trigger execution time of GAS in the business edition of G suite

Tags: google-apps-script

Please tell me how to check the total time of GAS trigger execution time in the G suite business edition.

1. On the trigger execution number screen, you can check the execution time for this trigger, but is there a way to check the total execution time of triggers executed without 24 hours?
2. In business edition, the total time of script execution time by trigger is less than 6 hours, but in the error notification without using 6 hours, a notice comes informed that "the computer time used on the day by service is too long" What other factors can be considered as a cause?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, for example, is this answer useful for your situation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48833148/7108653

Comment: Thanks for the advice.
Although it does not go out of speculation yet, it may be a phenomenon which occurred because it was under the following conditions.

· It was a GAS running on a spreadsheet originally created with a free Google account.
· Share the spreadsheet created with the above free account to the account of the G - suite business edition contracted later, delete all the triggers that were running under the free account, and re - register the trigger with the G - suite account.

Comment: Because of these things, since the owner of the spreadsheet is still a free account, was not it being operated with the limit of the trigger execution time of 90 minutes a day?
I made a hypothesis.
I changed the owner of the spreadsheet to the G suite account, deleted all the triggers once, set the trigger again, and I am seeing the current state.
I will report the situation afterwards.

I appreciate early advice.

Comment: Thank you for the additional information. I think that your consideration is correct. In your situation, it is considered that the owner of Spreadsheet is the free account and the quota of trigger time becomes 90 minutes. When the owner of Spreadsheet is transferred to the business account or new Spreadsheet is created by the business account, I think that the quota becomes larger than that of the free account.